# Word to name a group that sits between Junior and Senior

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a school system which 6 year levels. these 6 year levels are broken up into 3 groups. currently i have

- Junior (1st and 2nd year)
- _____ (3rd and 4th Year)
- Senior (5th and 6th Year)

i'm looking for a word that would fit in-between Junior and Senior which would also be used to name them.

Description Example

> The 6 year levels are broken up into 3 groups. Junior, _____ and Senior
>
> Juniors (1st and second years), being the newest, generally have more restrictions put on what they can do around campus than most to help them ease into school like at Astrea rather than become overwhelmed with all the difference from their previous schools. the Junior uniform is generally colored black
>
> ______s (3rd and 4th years), having gotten used to the unfamiliar school system of Astrea are given some freedoms such as being able to join Night Watch or the Student Council and not being under curfew if living in the dormitories. along with these ______s can selected up to 4 elective subject each year however one must be of the Magic Combat Training subset of subjects. the _____ uniform is general a dark rose colour.
>
> Seinors (5th and 6th years) have the most freedom and only need to take the core 4 subjects while the rest are all elective. of their electives they can choose to forgo study for almost 2 per seasonal term (_____s can only choose 1 and must get approval from their homeroom teacher and either their doom supervisor or an evaluation from the headmaster). Seniors can also gain access the break lounges scattered around the campus and can leave school grounds during school hours. the Senior uniform is white with an additional camisole-style lace garment dress over top imprinted with a student's elemental nature

Dialog Example:

> "You don't mind if i walk home with you?" Arietta asked.
>
> "do whatever you want" Suecia said walking off. the moody Undine didn't get far however before something yanked at the collar of her kimono
>
> "hey! that's not how you treat your kohai" a girl said pulling Suecia back "you're a _____ now and like our ______s before us we help our kohai Juniors"

Comment: In the US, the 4 years of conventional high school or college classes are referred to as freshman, sophomore, junior, and senior.  There is nothing between "junior" and "senior".  Though a few schools slip in a category known as "pre-senior".

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Memor-X's answer, you might consider assigning the title of "Juniors" to the intermediate class,  and rename the youngest class "Freshmen" or "Sophomores".

Alternatively, you could follow the practice of a number of private schools and have a "lower school", "middle school", and "upper school".